# How to export the build commands/script for a docker image, so that i can rerun for creating new image?

Tags: docker, command, extract

I built a docker container from a centos 7 image, and did a lot of customization by running many commands, but i didn't record the commands.
I want extract the command history as a Dockerfile, so that i can rerun it to rebuild it if the container get broken. i know save as a image file but i only want to save as text format Dockerfile.
how to do that? dear?

Thanks & Regards,
Martin.

Comment: Do you have that container still running?

Comment: Docker doesn't record that (in a way that tools like, say, **script**(1) might).  I don't think you can recover a Dockerfile from the state you're in now.  I'd suggest _starting_ by writing out the Dockerfile, repeating `docker build` until it's right, rather than trying to do things in an interactive shell in an ephemeral container.

Comment: Thanks David, you're right, i tried many ways and seems "writing out the Dockerfile, repeating docker build" is the right way to go, it's controllable and repeatable, thanks bro!

Comment: Hi mchawre, can be either running or down, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`docker history` command may be helpful (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/).

Comment: Hi Rui, the "docker history" output seems not exactly what i input previously, almost not re-useable, thank you anyway

Comment: `docker history` doesn't capture the commands you entered in the interactive terminal. If you want to extract those commands, maybe look at the `~/.bash_history`. You can access that via `docker start <container>; docker attach <container>; cat ~/.bash_history`